# Indicate line number thresold

Tags: line-numbers

How can I have a ruler displayed on a specific linenumber e.g. `20`?

Similar to `M-x ruler-mode` though for lines/rows instead of columns

Comment: Are you asking to have a column ruler displayed at some arbitrary line instead of across the top?

Comment: @naugiedoggie A horizontal line instead of a vertical